# Android 12 - Play audio through earpiece

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setCommunicationDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo) to set communication device to AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE with AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION.

Current code:

```
private fun setCommunicationDevice(context: Context, deviceType: Int) {
    val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    
    val devices = audioManager.availableCommunicationDevices
    for (device in devices) {
        if (device.type == deviceType) {
            val result = audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(device)
            Log.i(
                "EARPIECE_AUDIO_MANAGER",
                "setCommunicationDevice type:$deviceType result:$result"
            )
            if (result) break
        }
    }
}
```

When I play local audio files from any app, this does work but audio only plays for approx 5 seconds in earpiece and then goes back to speakers.

Comment: You should identify/show code how you are "playing audio" as https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setCommunicationDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo) is for `This method can be used by voice or video chat applications to select a different audio device than the one selected by default by the platform.` The functions you are using are more in the telephony stack than media playback stack (music / normal videos).

Comment: I was hoping this works alongside any mediaplayer app. So I have to create my own code for the same?